# problem with power.roc.test in R

Tags: roc

I anlaysing several different ROC analyses in my article. Therefore I am investigating whether my sample size is appropriate. I have created a data frame which consists all combinations of possible sample sizes for ROC analysis.

```
str(auc)
'data.frame':   93 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ cases   : int  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 ...
     $ controls: int  102 101 100 99 98 97 96 95 94 93 ...
```

My aim is to create line plot cases/controls (ie. kappa) versus optimal AUC

Hence I would like to create third variable using power.roc.test to calculate optimal AUC

I ran to problem above, where lies to problem?

```
auc$auc<-power.roc.test(sig.level=.05,power=.8,ncases=auc$cases,ncontrols=auc$controls)$auc
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : AUC could not be solved:
Error in uniroot(power.roc.test.optimize.auc.function, interval = c(0.5, : invalid function value in 'zeroin'
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In if (is.na(f.lower)) stop("f.lower = f(lower) is NA") :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (is.na(f.upper)) stop("f.upper = f(upper) is NA") :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In if (f.lower * f.upper > 0) stop("f() values at end points not of opposite sign") :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using the `pROC` package. The error message is not especially helpful here, but you basically need to pass scalar values, including to `ncases` and `ncontrols`.

```
power.roc.test(sig.level=.05,power=.8,ncases=10, ncontrols=102)
```

You can wrap that in some apply loop:

```
auc$auc<- apply(auc, 1, function(line) {
   power.roc.test(sig.level=.05, power=.8, ncases=line[["cases"]], ncontrols=line[["controls"]])$auc
})
```

Then you will be able to plot this however you want:

```
plot(auc$cases / auc$controls, auc$auc, type = "l")
```

Note that the AUC here is not the "optimal AUC", but the AUC at which you can expect the given power at the given significance level with the given sample size for a test of the significance of the AUC (H0: AUC = 0.5). Note that you won't be able to perform this test with `pROC` anyway.